# Может ли Heap Sort копировать все элементы?

Tags: java, алгоритм

Наткнулся на реализацию HeapSort на [wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Sorting/Heapsort) использующую копирование элементов в `PriorityQueue` и обратно в массив. Но ведь одно из главных преимуществ HeapSort в том что она не использует дополнительную память, а сортирует элементы "на месте".

Что это ошибка в справочнике или мое непонимание?

```
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
public static <E extends Comparable<? super E>> void heapsort(E[] array) {

    // Java's PriorityQueue class functions as a min heap
    PriorityQueue<E> heap = new PriorityQueue<E>(array.length);

    // Add each array element to the heap
    for (E e : array)
        heap.add(e);

    // Elements come off the heap in ascending order
    for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
        array[i] = heap.remove();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heap sort работает конкретно с деревом, а не массивом. Если бы вы в функцию передавали уже готовое дерево, то за сортировку бы отвечала только строка

```
for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
    array[i] = heap.remove();
```

В данной реализации предполагается, что передается массив, из которого нужно сделать дерево. Имеется ввиду, что не требуется дополнительная память, если данные представлены в виде дерева.

Answer (score 2):

Дополнительная память не требуется, если выстраивать кучу прямо в массиве.

Массив можно воспринимать как бинарное дерево, где под каждым `i`-ым элементом могут находиться его потомки под индексами `2i+1` и `2i+2`. При индексации с нуля, разумеется. Однако чтобы это дерево считать кучей, нужно привести элементы в соответствующий порядок. А затем, удаляя по верхушке на каждом шаге, кучу восстанавливать.

И этот алгоритм там приведён, под заголовком "In-place heapsort".

Comment: да да я вот это и имел в виду... получается что реализация которую я привел в вопросе заведомо проигрышная хоть и использует принцип heap sort но по характеристикам как бы не совсем ею является. Все-таки алгоритм и его сложность вещи сильно связанные, в конце концов не было бы вообще смысла в разных алгоритмах если бы их время работы и необходимые ресурсы не отличались в каком-от с заранее известном отношении. А тут все-таки странновато получается.

Comment: @Pavel я вообще не встречал хипсорта на явной внешней куче. Мне это даже алгоритмом не очень кажется, это просто применение структуры данных, которой свойственна сортировка содержимого. Алгоритм сортировки уже реализован в ней. Но похоже, что это спорная тема. Не буду делать выводов.

Comment: во во и я о том же...